# Get remote session name from the PS shell prompt

Tags: logging, powershell-remoting

I am creating an automation script that will be moving in and out and numerous PS Remote sessions. The connection process was built before my time and logging is minimal. I would like a way of reading the text that appears *before* the native PowerShell prompt after a remote connection is established. Example:

Starting here:

```
PS C:\>
```

Connection 1:

```
PS C:\> session01
```

New Prompt (what I would like to grab):

```
Session One Friendly Name PS C:\>
```

Connection 2:

```
Session One Friendly Name PS C:\> session21
```

New Prompt:

```
Session Twenty-One Friendly Name PS C:\>
```

And so on...

Can this information be captured? Would be very helpful for logging. I have tried variations of Get-History but that part isn't really a command and isn't captured as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get your need completely, but I Hope you want to capture the prompt.

you can do

```
Get-Contenet Function:\Prompt
```

to get prompt value and is an automatic function which executes on each carriage return.